# Signing in after registration , auth()->user() return null in DashboardController

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying Laravel for the 1st time . Im working right now in the signing in the user after the registration but it seems like the auth helper always gives me null value

Here is the code

```
//REGISTERCONTROLLER
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
       return view('auth.register');
   }

   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

        User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Here is the DashboardController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        dd(auth()->user());
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Here is the route web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;

Route::get('/dashboard',[DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/register',[RegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register',[RegisterController::class, 'store']);


Route::get('/posts', function () {
    return view('posts.index');
});
```

Another thing, the "attempt" word in the RegisterController seems undefined according to the VSCode

Comment: You alreday make your password with HASH method `Hash::make($request->password),` so this line `auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));` wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change :

```
$password = Hash::make($request->password);

User::create([
      'name' => $request->name,
      'username' => $request->username,
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => $password,
]);

auth()->attempt('email' => $request->email, 'password' => $password);

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    return view('dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because Auth::attempt hashes the password using bcrypt, so if the password in your database is not hashed(bcrypted) the attempt method will always fail because passwords will never matche.
Please try to hash the password before register your user and tell me if this is solves the problem

Comment: As you can see at the REGISTERCONTROLLER the password is hashed. is that what you are telling?

Comment: Yeah that's it, you need first to hash it and then pass it as normal variable !

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $user = Auth::user();  //this will return the authenticated user
    return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the VSCode and then it works fine suddenly. i didnt do anything.